# Adding buttons below GraphView, all inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-graphview

I have been trying to add Button's below a GraphView, and all these elements are part of a Fragment. Tried many approaches but none of them worked properly.
This is the layout file for the Fragment (fragment_graph.xml).

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.nma.util.sdcardtrac.GraphFragment">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/graph_fragment_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

And this is the Java code dynamically adding a graph and button, placed in the Fragment's `onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)`.

```
storageGraph = new LineGraphView(getActivity(), graphLabel);
storageGraph.addSeries(graphSeries); // More config calls follow
...
LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.graph_fragment_layout);
Button button = new Button(getActivity());
button.setText("Test");
view.addView(storageGraph);
view.addView(button);
```

The Button is not visible though I have set orientation to vertical for the LinearLayout containing it.

**EDIT - solved!**

I found that nesting the graph under its own LinearLayout and the buttons under another LinearLayout, and both of these wrapped in a LinearLayout fixed the problem! The LinearLayout containing the graph must be weighted (I chose a weight of 0.8).
Layout file looks like:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.nma.util.sdcardtrac.GraphFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/graph_fragment_wrap"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:id="@+id/graph_fragment_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/graph_buttons"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_navigation_previous_item"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_navigation_next_item"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried it and it works. Perhaps your graph is taking all the available space, so added button is below the screen? Try to wrap your LinearLayout into a ScrollView and see if there is a button in the bottom.

Comment: Wrapping the LinearLayout in a ScrollView now only shows the button but not the graph!